# extra_context variables are not passed to changelist template

Tags: django, django-templates

Trying to modify standard admin list template, for this I'm passing extra_context:

```
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['stats'] = 'test'
        resp_view=super().changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
        return resp_view
```

And using this in the template:

```
...
<div class="results">
  <p>
    Statistics: {{ stats }}
  </p>    
  <table id="result_list">
...
```

But it doesn't pass it for some reason. Although when I look into the fields of resp_view, it's in the context data:

```
(Pdb) p resp_view.context_data
{'site_title': 'Django site admin', ..., 'stats': 'test'}
```

What can be the problem here? I understand it's official way of passing extra variables into the template?

Admin class:

```
class bet_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('timestamp', 'bookmaker', 'account_', 'sport', 'stake',
                  'description', 'result', 'profit', 'discrepancy', 'betnumber')
    list_filter = (
        ('timestamp', PastDateRangeFilter),
    )
    ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        '''Bets are added by scrapers only'''
        return False

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['stats'] = 'test'
        resp_view=super().changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
        breakpoint()
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)

    # Strip bookmaker, since it lives in separate column
    def account_(self, instance): return instance.account.username
    account_.short_description='account'
```

Comment: Can you include the whole admin class? From what you've put here it doesn't look incorrect.

Comment: @markwalker_, tried to remove everything else save changelist_view(), modifying the contrib/admin/template/admin template, the same.

Comment: @markwalker_ I've found what's happening, so need to use change_list template apparently. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py:result_list_tag()

InclusionAdminNode is invoked with takes_context=False, therefore parent context is not propagated, and so all the variables from extra_context won't be visible in change_list_results template.

I've no idea why it's done like this, but it's so.